# Several Main Methods (UI and Logic)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, program-entry-point

it's the first time I do an User Interface, and I'm trying to understand how the main methods works here. Because in the logic part I have a main method, just one obviously, but in the UI I have one main method per each JFrame like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SFile frame = new SFile();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

What should I do, delete this methods, change the things in the method to another site?

Thank you.

Comment: how the main method works doesn't change. It's just the code in it that changes.

Comment: I don't see multiple main methods in your question. What is your actual question? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Your main method creates and shows a JFrame, and then exits.  That's all it does,  The invokeLater method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the Event Dispatch Thread.  Nothing else happens until an action is triggered, usually by left-clicking on a button.  This is called an event driven application.

Comment: I have a method in logic, that i want to use as my main method, and several methods that java swing generates me (one per JFrame). The thing is I don't know how the main methods of the UI works, what I need from this mains of Swing, and how could i make one single method on the logic part for call the entire UI system, and make it works. That code is a sample of a JFrame main method.

Comment: I want to open and close this JFrames  from a single main method out of UI part. Is it possible?

Comment: *generates me (one per JFrame).* - your application should NOT have multiple JFrames. When you start your application you create a display a single JFrame. Then through user iteraction you may want to display other windows. In this case you would create and display a JDialog, but this is only done in your application code, not in the main() method. For example see the `FileChooserDemo.java` example code found in [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). The frame is display and when you click on a button a dialog is displayed.

Comment: In the example the dialog is part of the JDK. In your case you would code you own custom JDialog.